# gridsearchcv taking too much time and throwing random errors?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I have been struggling with Gridsearchcv for a long time now.

After vectorizing my train data I used grid search for efficient parameter setting but i am getting continuous errors .

My code is something like this :

```
x = HashVectorizer().fit_transform( train_data.data ) 
parameters = { "c" : [0.001 , 0.01 , 0.1 , 1 , 10 , 100 , 1000]}
if __name__ == "__main__":# i recetly fixed this error 
    clf = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression() , parameters , n_jobs = -1 , verbose = 1)
   train = clf.fit( x , x.label)


y = HashVectorizer().transform( test_data.data )
   test = clf.predict(y)# here is my PROBLEM line , the error is coming as "clf is not defined "
```

But I have defined `clf` , also after checking [gridsearchcv documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#grid-search-searching-for-estimator-parameters) I found nothing of help .

Please help.

Comment: strange ; cannot reproduce the error ; maybe it has to do with your lower case `c` in `parameters` when `LogisticRegression` accepts a capital `C` as a parameter

Comment: i have a C this is just a typo

Comment: if i don't look for parameter tuning my code runs fine @Jacquot

Comment: @Jacquot i am thinking the problem is somewhere in indentation , do i have to indent the last two lines in if __name__ == "__main__" ?

Comment: cannot hurt, or get rid of it altogether ; i admit I have never used `if __name__ == "__main__":`, it's more of a software engineering stuff ; maybe also defining `lr = LogisticRegression()` before `clf = GridSearchCV(lr, ...)`

Comment: if __name__ = "__main__" is important as i m using windows , i would try       lr = LogisticRegression()

Comment: @Jacquot it worked i just indented everything in ' if __name__ =="__main__"' :)

Answer (score 0):

Move and align your code with IF statement. Bease you are defining clf under IF statement which is local to them.